# Facebook Prophet error: cmdstanpy - ERROR - Chain [1] error: terminated by signal 11 Unknown error -11

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, facebook-prophet

I am trying to train Facebook's prophet on timeseries data.
[Data I used, one column named ds and another y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Bqs7.png)

During fitting however I get this error first :

[first error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LrVh.png)

followed by

[second error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSYfp.png)

Does anyone know why this is the case? Thanks!

I tried searching for the problem online and could not find a solution. I tried installing cmdstanpy version 0.9.5 and reinstalling prophet but it did not work so I am a bit stuck. I am running python 3.7.12 version.